# Mac OSX Server - Moved 20 iMacs from one group to another with the exact same settings now disconnecting from wifi

Tags: network, wifi, imac, server.app

When the new settings are being applied it disconnects wifi, this means they never actually get the new settings and consistently are disconnecting from wifi everytime the settings are pushed out (which is constantly).

If i manually attempt to install the profile halfway through it will disconnect from wifi and then complain it cant connect to active directory server.

Any ideas as this issue hasn't been reported anywhere on the internet.

Answer (score 1):

Found a workaround, removed the active directory binding settings from profile manager, settings now pushing without disconnecting wifi everytime.